# What is אנדרלמוסיא

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, words, theology, theodicy

It is quite clear from context that it means a type of heavenly group punishment, like [a flood](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Bereshit.12.1?vhe=Midrash_Tanchuma_--_Torat_Emet&lang=bi) or [a plague](https://www.sefaria.org/Matnot_Kehunah_on_Bereshit_Rabbah.26.5.6?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah,_Vilna,_1878&lang=bi)* where both [good and bad die](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah.695.2?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah&qh=%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%A0%D6%B0%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%9C%D6%B8%D7%9E%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%A1%D6%B0%D7%99%D6%B8%D7%90), l'a. It seems mainly connected with the sin of זִּמָּה/זְנוּת i.e. inappropriate sexual behaviour, on a societal level. It is associated in several places with a teaching [from Rabbi Yehoshua Ben Levi](https://www.sefaria.org/Reshit_Chokhmah%2C_Gate_of_Holiness.17.44?vhe=Hamesorah_Publishers,_Jerusalem_2005&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that this is one sin that Hashem does not overlook.

**My question is, is that all we know about it?**

I would still love to hear from an expert who has studied the word and concept and its use in Torah. Some questions that come to mind:

1. How did this particular greek word/idea make its way into Chazal? Perhaps through Rabbi Yehoshua Ben Levi?
2. What is its original meaning and other etymology? Perhaps it is [Androlepsy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androlepsy)? This is how Berman translates it in [Midrash Tanhuma-Yelammedenu](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990013504580205171/NLI).
3. Why is there no Hebrew word for this?
4. Why does the word not seem to appear much outside of a handful of Midrashim?
5. Are there any other words for this concept in use?
6. Where would be some good sources that discuss the concept itself?
7. Any other interesting, and on topic information about אנדרלמוסיא

---

* Note the different wording in [this](https://www.sefaria.org/Matnot_Kehunah_on_Vayikra_Rabbah.23.9.2?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah,_Vilna,_1878&qh=%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%A0%D6%B0%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%9C%D6%B8%D7%9E%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%A1%D6%B0%D7%99%D6%B8%D7%90) definition

Comment: In modern Hebrew, it's used to mean a mess or a lack of order, similar to בלאגן balagan

Comment: In the context of [Tanchuma B'midbar 32](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma_Buber%2C_Bamidbar.32.1?lang=bi) and [B'midbar Rabba 5:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.5.3?lang=bi) it seems to refer to something related to androlepsy: "אין מדתו של הקב"ה כמדת בשר ודם מלך בשר ודם שמרדה עליו מדינה הוא עושה בה אנדרולומוסיא והורג הטובים עם הרעים ואינו אומר זה חטא וזה לא חטא אלא הורג את כולה והקב"ה אינו כן אלא בשעה שהדור מכעיס לפניו הוא ממלט את הצדיקים ומאבד את הרשעים".

Comment: "How did this particular greek word/idea make its way into Chazal? Perhaps through Rabbi Yehoshua Ben Levi?" R. Saul Lieberman wrote two books on the topic of the Hellenic/Rabbinic interaction

Comment: @Fred maybe that should be question number 8 - how did it change phonetics

Comment: @RabbiKaii There's often some corruption when a word migrates to another language, and this is often true as well when Greek words migrated into the Talmudic-era Aramaic lexicon.

Comment: @Fred sounds like there's a lot to learn

Comment: @RabbiKaii ארוכה מארץ מדה ורחבה מני ים :)

Comment: There are a lot of Greek words in Chazal, presumably from the Greek presence in Israel. I remember reading that they are more common in works of Chazal written in Israel as opposed to Bavel.